# Access database from layout.cshtml in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a set of users in a model like this:

```
[Key]
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Employee")]
        public int? EmployeeID  { get; set; }

        public int? CompanyID { get; set; }

        public string UserID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Middlenames { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Postnumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime EditedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CurrentLoginTime { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime LastLoginTime { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

What i want to do, is display an menuitem in my layout file based on if companyID have a value.

In MVC5 I could do that in an instant, but in .net core I have no Idea on how to proceed or what to search for.

I hope that someone here can tell me, how this works and how i should do it :-)

Comment: What exactly is `IsCompanyOwner`? It’s not a property on your user object.

Comment: @model User
and
@if(model.IsCompanyOwner){}. It's the same as asp MVC

Comment: Are you asking how to do a controller's job in `layout.cshtml` (bad idea) or how to access the model in there? Why would the *layout* file need to know about a specific controller's model? That's the job of the controller's views, or the Razor Page

Comment: I can't see `IsCompanyOwner` either. But maybe you are helped with a `@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager` in the top of your file.

Comment: I edited the post since "IsCompanyOwner" is part of another model. What i want to do, is hide or display an menuitem based on, if the Companyid is set in the UserInfo model for the current logged in user ;-)

Comment: It might be helpful to explain how you've handled this in MVC5 before.

Comment: I accessed the db from the models, and created methods that i could access from anywhere. So i could just create a method in UserInfo class that returns a bool and then call that method from the layout :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do here is create some service (and register it with the DI container) that had a way to figure out your condition. You can then inject that service into your view and call a method on it to check the value:

```
@inject MyUserService myUserService
@if (await myUserService.GetIsCompanyOwnerAsync(User))
{
    <div>Item for company owner</div>
}
```

In your service you can then e.g. inject your database context and query for the user according to the current user:

```
public class MyUserService
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    public MyUserService(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetIsCompanyOwnerAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(user);
        return user.CompanyID.HasValue;
    }
}
```

Note that this will cause a database query on every request in order to render that in the layout. In the long run, it would be better to expose this property directly as a claim on the claims principal, e.g. as a `OwnsCompany` claim. That way, you could just check for the claim directly in the view:

```
@if (await User.FindFirst("OwnsCompany") != null)
{
    <div>Item for company owner</div>
}
```

Comment: I ended up making an applicationUser model that inherrits from IdentityUser and then adding the properties i needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ViewBag.IsCompanyOwnerMenuVisible` and assign to it your logic:

### Controller:

```
ViewBag.IsCompanyOwnerMenuVisible = userInfo.CompanyID.HasValue;
```

then inside your view:

### View:

```
@if(ViewBag.IsCompanyOwnerMenuVisible)
{
    //Your menu code here
}
```

or you can check it directly inside view:

```
@if(Model.CompanyID.HasValue)
{
    //Your menu code here
}
```

Comment: I would then have to set that viewbag in every controller that uses that layout? or is there a smarter way to do that? (It might be me that dosnt understand how Core works ;-))

Comment: Is your shared model, model for your view? Check updated answer.

Comment: Im not really sure how i pass a model to layout.cshtml? Viewbag and viewdata from controller cant be accessed from the layout view. They just return null, which is probably becourse the layout renders before the viewbag is created.

Comment: In that situation you can create Base controller, and derive all your common controllers from your Base controller, then inside that controller you can override `OnActionExecuting` method, and assing your ViewBag's there.

Comment: Or just override `OnActionExecuting ` inside your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making an ApplicationUser class that inherrits from IdentityUser. I could then change all the places that IdentityUser pops up in my project to ApplicationUser.

In applicationUser I then added the properties i needed, added the migration with Add-migration and updated the database.

My ApplicationUser class looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimePlus.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my layout i could then call the properties with:

```
<li>
   <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">
           Hello @user.Fullname
   </a>
</li>
```

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tW5QwWPKXaY

Hope this helps other people :-)
I marked "poke"'s answer as it was his pointer to claims that got me googling ;-)